# Remedy for Varna Sankar वर्ण संकर?

Tags: scripture, puranas, bhagavad-gita, varna, sraddha

Gita (1.40 - 1.42) talks about varna shankar, can not perform shraddha/tarpan, hence his ptiris fall to hell along with him.

```
सङ्करो नरकायैव कुलघ्नानां कुलस्य च |
पतन्ति पितरो ह्येषां लुप्तपिण्डोदकक्रिया: || 42||
```

English Translation ([Source](https://www.yugalsarkar.com/bhagwad-gita-chapter-1-shlok-42-english))

```
1.42 And the intermingling in the family leads the ruiners of the family 
verily into hell. The forefathers of these fall down (into hell) 
because of being deprived of the offerings of rice-balls and water.
```

So, a varna shankar can not perform shraddha, and hence his ptiris fall to hell along with him.

Unfortunately, in this day and age, there are many Inter caste marriages. They also cause "Varna Shankar".

**How can "Varna Shankar" already born, rectify this and perform shraddha ?**

*Please give sashstra reference, as far as possible.*

Comment: As per Dharmasutras of Gautama 4.22  you need to wait till 7th generation. It is only corrected at that point in time. The progeny from 7th generation and beyond can then help free the pitris

Comment: The other alternative is if father in law is Shukracharya, who was able to ensure Yayati didn't incur any sin for his pratiloma vivah with Devayani :-)

Comment: @Carmensandiego It seems tragic having to wait so long to free pitris. Is there a faster way or another way to free pitris ?